# Reverse engineer linear model $Ax+c=y$. Given $x$ and $y$, find $A$ and $c$

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, least-squares

Consider the standard linear model linear, given by the matrix equation

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}\vec{b}_{i}+\vec{c} & =\vec{y}_{i}\,,
\end{align*}
where vector $\vec{b}_{i}$ denotes the input to the model, $\vec{y}_{i}$
the output of the model, while $\mathbf{A}$ and $\vec{c}$ are the
matrix and constant-offset vector of the linear model. Typically,
in least squares, $\mathbf{A}$, $\vec{c}$, and $\vec{y}_{i}$ are
known, and one wishes to find $\vec{\beta}_{i}$.

Here, instead, we wish to consider the model matrix and vector, $\mathbf{A}$
and $\vec{c}$, as a black box that we can empirically test. We run
$N$ experiments with a set of known inputs $\vec{b}_{i}\in\left\{ \vec{b}_{1},\ldots,\vec{b}_{N}\right\} $
and a corresponding set of known, observed outcomes $\vec{y}_{i}\in\left\{ \vec{y}_{1},\ldots,\vec{y}_{N}\right\} $.
Based on the known vector data, we wish to ``reverse-engineer''
the black-box consisting of the unknown $\mathbf{A}$ and $\vec{c}$.

This seems like a textbook problem that should be treated somewhere,
and probably has a name. I hope someone could help educate me on this
and point me to a reference or textbook.

In the absence of that, let me propose an approach to the solution,
but perhaps there is a much better way? For each data set $i$, we
have a matrix equation like this, which, here, we take to be 3 dimensional,

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}A_{xx} & A_{xy} & A_{xz}\\
A_{yx} & A_{yy} & A_{yz}\\
A_{zx} & A_{zy} & A_{zz}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b_{i,x}\\
b_{i,y}\\
b_{i,z}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}c_{x}\\
c_{y}\\
c_{z}
\end{pmatrix} & =\begin{pmatrix}y_{i,x}\\
y_{i,y}\\
y_{i,z}
\end{pmatrix}\,.\label{eq:z1}
\end{align}
We could vectorize the matrix and constants, (and slightly change
the notation) 
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{\beta} & \equiv\left(A_{xx},A_{xy},\ldots,A_{zz},c_{x},c_{y},c_{z}\right)^{\mathrm{T}},\\
\mathbf{X}_{i} & \equiv\begin{pmatrix}b_{i,x} & b_{i,y} & b_{i,z} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  & b_{i,x} & b_{i,y} & b_{i,z} &  &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & b_{i,x} & b_{i,y} & b_{i,z} &  &  & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf{y}_{i} & \equiv\begin{pmatrix}y_{i,x}\\
y_{i,y}\\
y_{i,z}
\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align*}
In view of this, the equation above takes the form 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{X}_{i}\boldsymbol{\beta} & = & \mathbf{y}_{i}\,\forall i\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
To take account of all the data, we can vertically concatenate all
the matrix equations, and define the partitioned matrix of known inputs
to the system
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{X} & \equiv & \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}_{1}\\
\hline \vdots\\
\hline \mathbf{X}_{N}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a $3N\times12$ matrix, since there are 3 rows per data set,
and the number of unknown are 12, and there are 12 datasets. The corresponding
known output data matrix is 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y} & \equiv\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{y}_{1}\\
\hline \vdots\\
\hline \mathbf{y}_{N}
\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align*}
Thus the complete matrix equation is in the standard least-squares
form
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} & = & \mathbf{y}\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
This allows us to employ the standard method of least squares to an
overdetermined system of equations

\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} & = & (\mathbf{X}^{{\rm T}}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{{\rm T}}\mathbf{y},
\end{eqnarray*}
 where $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ is the least square solution vector,
which contains all the information necessary to find out what $\mathbf{A}$
and $\vec{c}$ are in the first equation.

Would this be the advisable way to solve this kind of problem on a
computer program? (e.g., numpy in python). This question seems like
a textbook kind of problem, but after some digging around I couldn't
find anything. Perhaps you can educate me on what this type of problem
is called, and what a good go to reference to read up on it would
it. Thank you, this would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is $y$ in your model??

Comment: @SZN  Thanks. Just updated, hopefully more clear now.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: Nice, so this is what you would do as well? Does this have a name or a place to dig more? I thought it would be a common problem in some field of math

Comment: I'd use this if it worked. You can generate some random matrices according to your rule and see how well it works. The only thing I know even remotely like this is the orthogonal Procrutes problem (Wabha's problem) which assumes $A$ is a rotation matrix and $c = 0$. In that case it turns out you can use quaternions, but I doubt there is a similar approach for general matrices $A$.

Comment: Also -- look at singular value decomposition. An alternative way of solving the Procrustes problem without quaternions that might generalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Augment the matrix $A$ with the vector $c$ as an extra column. Then augment each vector $b_i$ with an extra component equal to unity. The $y_i$ vectors are unchanged.

Now the equations read
$$Ab_i = y_i$$
where the quantities on the LHS are augmented as described above.

But the indexed vectors are really just columns of their constituent matrices, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 b_i &= Be_i \cr
 y_i &= Ye_i \cr
}$$

And so we have arrived at a purely matrix equation, which can be solved by standard techniques.
$$\eqalign{
 AB &= Y \cr
 ABB^T &= YB^T \cr
 A &= YB^T(BB^T)^{-1} \cr
}$$

Comment: Great! This looks like a more straightforward solution, and has essentially the same form as the least squares solution, $ \boldsymbol{\hat\beta} =( X ^TX)^{-1}X^T \boldsymbol y$, except that it is the transpose.  How do i know that $BB^T$ has an inverse?

Comment: In general, you don't know if $BB^T$ or $X^TX$ (or any other matrix) will have an inverse. To be safe, you should utilize the Moore-Penrose inverse, i.e. $$\eqalign{A&=YB^+\cr \beta &= X^+y}$$ which exists for all matrices.

Comment: Practically speaking, the more columns you can add to $B$ the more likely the rows of $B$ will be linearly independent (so $B$ will be full rank.and $BB^T$ will be invertible).  The likelihood $B$ is not full rank diminishes geometrically with each extra column.  The likelihood $BB^T$ is poorly numerically conditioned diminishes similarly, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It can be much simpler.  Use $n+1$ test vectors, one of all zeroes, and $n$ each with a single $1$ and the rest $0$.  Put all these vectors into a $n$ by $n+1$ matrix called $\mathrm{X}$ that looks like $[\mathrm{I}\ 0]$ or

$$\mathrm{X} = \left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Plug each of the vectors into the transformation, and look at the result like $\left[M\ c\right]$.  $c$ is the $c$ from the transformation equation, and $\mathrm{A} = M - c^t \mathrm{I}$

Comment: Nice, right, you say, that there are n+1 special input vectors that are informationally  maximally orthogonal and complete. If we can make these and plug them into the model with good fidelity, then its straightforward. Indeed, for the zero vector y (b = 0) = c,  so the output directly gives us c. Agreed, this is more straightforward. The issue, which i haven't specified above, is that in the application of interest, i am not able to plug in the 0 vector easily, and there might be some noise on the other inputs, so having more of them should help (i think) to overconstrain the fit problem.

Comment: Real world data? Eww, that has errors.  Looks like you're stuck with least squares then.

Comment: Life is complex: it has both real and imaginary components. Thanks though, still useful  :)

Answer (score 1):

We have the following linear model

$$\rm y = A x + b$$

where $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathrm y \in \mathbb R^m$, $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $\mathrm b \in \mathbb R^m$. Vectorizing, we obtain an **underdetermined** system of $m$ linear equations in $m n + m = m (n+1)$ variables

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x^\top \otimes \mathrm I_m & \mathrm I_m\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A)\\ \mathrm b\end{bmatrix} = \mathrm y$$

Since the matrix has *full row rank* for all $\rm x$, the **least-norm** solution of the linear system is

$$\begin{array}{rl} \begin{bmatrix} \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A_{\text{LN}})\\ \mathrm b_{\text{LN}}\end{bmatrix} &:= \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \otimes \mathrm I_m \\ \mathrm I_m\end{bmatrix} \left( \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x^\top \otimes \mathrm I_m & \mathrm I_m\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \otimes \mathrm I_m \\ \mathrm I_m\end{bmatrix} \right)^{-1} \mathrm y\\ &\,= \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \otimes \mathrm I_m \\ \mathrm I_m\end{bmatrix} \left( (\mathrm x^\top \otimes \mathrm I_m) (\mathrm x \otimes \mathrm I_m) + \mathrm I_m \right)^{-1} \mathrm y\\ &\,= \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \otimes \mathrm I_m \\ \mathrm I_m\end{bmatrix} \left( (\mathrm x^\top \mathrm x \otimes \mathrm I_m) + \mathrm I_m \right)^{-1} \mathrm y\\ &\,= \frac{1}{ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 + 1} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \otimes \mathrm I_m \\ \mathrm I_m\end{bmatrix} \mathrm y\\ &\,= \frac{1}{ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 + 1} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x \otimes \mathrm y \\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix}\end{array}$$

Un-vectorizing, we obtain

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{rl} \mathrm A_{\text{LN}} &:= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 + 1} \, \mathrm y \mathrm x^\top}\\\\ \mathrm b_{\text{LN}} &:= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 + 1} \, \mathrm y}\end{array}}$$

Verifying,

$$\mathrm A_{\text{LN}} \mathrm x + \mathrm b_{\text{LN}} = \frac{1}{ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 + 1} \left( \mathrm y \mathrm x^\top \mathrm x + \mathrm y \right) = \left(\frac{ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 + 1 }{ \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 + 1 } \right) \mathrm y = \mathrm y$$